# "UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device. Ignoring UIStatusBarStyle key in Info.plist." - What to do?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a universal binary app for iPhone / iPad. In console I always get this log:

> UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is
>   not available on this device. Ignoring
>   UIStatusBarStyle key in Info.plist.

Must I be worried about anything now? There's just one info.plist for both, right? How could I stop this log to happen? I guess it spams up the crashlogs if I leave it in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just one plist. It may be possible to specify a different value for the iPad for that key but I'm not sure if it's supported for that key.

It doesn't sound like a huge deal really. You could just remove it from the plist and set it programmaticly. It looks like if you try to set it on an iPad it just sets the status bar to black, so there's not too much reason to even check the UI idiom....

Anyway, see the Information Property List Key Reference docs if you want to try it.

> In iOS 3.2 and later, applications can
>   designate keys in the Info.plist file
>   as being applicable only to specific
>   types of devices. To create a
>   device-specific key, you combine the
>   key name with some special qualifiers
>   using the following pattern:
>
> key_root-~
>
> In this pattern, the key_root portion
>   represents the original name of the
>   key. The  and 
>   portions are both optional endings
>   that you can use to apply keys to
>   specific platforms or devices.
>   Currently the only platform you can
>   specify is iphoneos.
>
> To apply a key to a specific device,
>   you can use one of the following
>   values:
>
> iphone - The key applies to iPhone
>   devices. ipod - The key applies to
>   iPod touch devices. ipad - The key
>   applies to iPad devices. When
>   searching for a key in your
>   application’s Info.plist file, the
>   system chooses the key that is most
>   specific to the current device. For
>   example, to indicate that you want
>   your application to launch in a
>   portrait orientation on iPhone and
>   iPod touch devices but in
>   landscape-right on iPad, you would
>   configure your Info.plist with the
>   following keys: