# Does iOS simulator have the ability to simulate the device's camera?

Tags: ipad, ios6, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode4.5

Just to make sure I have all the code right, here is my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    IBOutlet UIButton *choosePhoto;
    IBOutlet UIButton *takePhoto;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIButton *choosePhoto;

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIButton *takePhoto;

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;

-(IBAction)getPhoto:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender;

@end
```

And then here is my implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize imageView,choosePhoto,takePhoto;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(IBAction)getPhoto:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker2.delegate = self;
    picker2.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

I have two `UIButtons` and a `UIIImageView` in my interface builder. The test app builds fine, no problems at all but when I press either the choose photo or take photo buttons the app crashes. Is this just because the simulator technically does not have either or a camera or a library to of photos to choose from? This is the error it gives me:  `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent` is not available on this device.

`Cameratest[8290:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController`

Advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, it doesn't, but the error is not even this. Try reading and understanding the error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/25-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html

> **Hardware Simulation Support**
>
> iOS Simulator doesn’t simulate accelerometer or camera hardware.

Additionally, H2CO3 is right, you've got a different problem and the error message is pretty clear:

'On iPad, UIIMagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'

A quick google search pointed me to the link below. Check out Zubair's response. I think you need to present the UIImagePickerController in a popover when running on iPad.

[UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971081/uistatusbarstyleblacktranslucent-is-not-available-on-this-device)

Comment: Thank you, I just googled the UIPopoverController myself and have found a solution that works. But yes, the camera is still a no go so thank you for supplying that link!

Answer (score 0):

No simulator doesn't support to simulate camera. For camera you have to run app on device